# display image but shows an array

Tags: php

I am creating a newsletter and I want to display my database image which I have inserted by `name` into my database. when I try to display image, but image is not displayed.

```
$date = $_POST['date'];

$qry_banner = "INSERT INTO `banner_tbl`(`banner_img`, `date`) VALUES ('$img_banner','$date')";
$res_banner = mysql_query($qry_banner);
$banner_tbl_id = mysql_insert_id();


$sec_id = $_POST['sectionID'];
$sec_active_image = $_POST['activeimage'];
$sec_title = $_POST['section_title'];


$total_sec = count($sec_id);

for($i=0;$i<$total_sec;$i++) 
{
$qry_section1 = "INSERT INTO `section_lt_tbl`(`banner_id`, `sectionID`, `activeimage`, `sectiontitle`) VALUES 
('$banner_tbl_id','$sec_id[$i]','$sec_active_image[$i]','$sec_title[$i]')";

 $nav_1_img = mysql_query("SELECT `activeimage` FROM `section_lt_tbl` WHERE sectionID = '1' limit 1");
 $nav_2_img = mysql_query("SELECT `activeimage` FROM `section_lt_tbl` WHERE sectionID = '2' limit 1");
 $nav_3_img = mysql_query("SELECT `activeimage` FROM `section_lt_tbl` WHERE sectionID = '3' limit 1");
 $nav_4_img = mysql_query("SELECT `activeimage` FROM `section_lt_tbl` WHERE sectionID = '4' limit 1");

$res_section1 = mysql_query($qry_section1);
$sec_tbl_id1 = mysql_insert_id();

$section_generated_id[] = $sec_tbl_id1;

}
 $nav_1_img_val = mysql_fetch_assoc ($nav_1_img);
 $nav_2_img_val = mysql_fetch_assoc ($nav_2_img);
 $nav_3_img_val = mysql_fetch_assoc ($nav_3_img);
 $nav_4_img_val = mysql_fetch_assoc ($nav_4_img);
```

Below is my html code where I'm trying to display image:

```
<td bgcolor="#dbdbdb" align="center"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="550" align="center">
       <tr>

       <td width="25%"><a href="#featuredstartup"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $nav_1_img_val ?>_blue.jpg" width="125px" height="134px" />
</a></td>
       <td width="25%"><a href="#healthcaredeals"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $nav_2_img_val ?>_grey.jpg" width="125px" height="134px" /></a></td>
       <td width="25%"><a href="#healthcarenews"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $nav_3_img_val ?>_grey.jpg" width="125px" height="134px" /></a></td>
       <td width="25%"><a href="#healthcaremarkets"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $nav_4_img_val ?>_grey.jpg" width="125px" height="134px" /></a></td>

       </tr>
       </table>
       </td>
```

Comment: you can select all images with one `mysql_query`

Answer (score 2):

Modify your img src tag to following.

```
<img src="uploads/<?php echo $nav_1_img_val['activeimage'] ?>_blue.jpg" width="125px" height="134px" />
```

mysql_fetch_assoc() will return you an associative array and you have to fetch the corresponding key value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$nav_1_img_val['activeimage']` instead of `$nav_1_img_val` because [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) is returning an array.

You should also think about moving to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) because [mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is deprecated.

Comment: yeah. definitely will move to mysqli now. do you know about any latest php-mysqli tutorial?

Comment: @chintansuthar check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189 not telling its complete but you may found it informative

Comment: @NullPoiиteя sure i will check this link. and thank you to suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array.

> You need to access the value of the array by using the name of the
>   column as key.

```
 $nav_1_img_result = mysql_fetch_assoc ($nav_1_img);
 $nav_1_img_val = $nav_1_img_result['activeimage'];
```